# MariaDB 10.1.38 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb

I have a table that has 3 columns:

```
id(int 11)  | user_id(int 4) | title(varchar 512) 
____________|________________|___________________
     1      |        3       | Thing X
     2      |        3       | Something Else
     3      |        5       | Thing X
```

And i need to make a unique combination between `user_id` and `title`. For that i'm using this simple query:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD UNIQUE `unique_post`(`user_id`, `title`)
```

The charset for the `title` column is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. The database was created using the charset `utf8mb4`:

```
CREATE DATABASE learning_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And the table type is `InnoDB`.

I've tried to set a few globals:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=on;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=on;
```

But i'm getting the same error `1071`:

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Is there anything else that i might be able to do?

P.S: if i set to index only the first `191` characters of the `title` i don't get that error:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD UNIQUE `unique_post`(`user_id`, `title`(191))
```

...but i have titles related to the same user that might be different only at the very last letter(aka last 4 bytes considering my charset)

P.S.S: i'm on localhost (using xampp).

Comment: Add stored calculated field with the value `value = hash(title)`, where 'hash' is any built-in chechsum function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html). Then create unique index by user_id and this calculated field. Of course, collision is possible, but its probability is too low (dependent by hash length).

Comment: [_This_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) has 5 workarounds.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok so after a weekend long of research the answer is very simple and i'm going to leave it here for others facing this same problem.

This answer is tested on MariaDB 10.1.38, db charset `utf8mb4`, table type `InnoDB` and table charset `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`:

Open `my.ini` and add this lines(if they already exist just edit everything after `=`) right after [mysqld]:

```
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = on
innodb_default_row_format = dynamic
innodb_large_prefix = 1
innodb_file_format_max = Barracuda
```

You can also set them trough the cmd/terminal:

On windows - if your XAMPP is located at `c:\xampp\`:

Open up a cmd and navigate to `mysql`'s bin - in this case:

```
cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin
```

Autenticate:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root
```

Once you're authenticated run this queries(one at a time):

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = on;
SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format = dynamic;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix = 1;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format_max = Barracuda;
```

But i recommend sticking to editing the my.ini(or .cnf) since if you are going for queries your options might by rewritten every time you restart your Apache.

You can read more on the `InnoDB` storage format: [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-storage-formats/)

Also this article is very interesting in helping you to optimize your `varchars` brefore creating the `unique keys`: [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/mysql-varchar-length-and-performance/76470#76470)

Comment: On Linux, you most probably will have to add the above lines to `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` under the `[mariadb]` section header.
See here: https://keawe.de/mariadb-innodb-keycloak

Comment: for Ubuntu - created `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/60-fix-key-length.cnf` with these entries under [mysqld]. Works like a charm.

Comment: I had to remove out line `innodb_default_row_format = dynamic` else MariaDB would't start on CentOs. But even without this option I got rid of the error.

Comment: In the latest version of MariaDB this does not work. The `innodb_file_format_max = Barracuda` makes MariaDB crash when starting.